# Scale STL to ruler in reference image

Tags: 3d-printing, scale

I am trying to scale an STL of a potential medical device to custom fit a patient. Is there a simple way to take a measurement over the reference image and tell the system that this measurement is X and have the entire scene and objects scaled according to that measurement?

For instance in the attached image, I would like to measure a line over the ruler and tell Blender that that measurement is 10cm.

I have tried manually scaling the reference image down, however then all the objects in the scene are too small for me to zoom in and work with.

Thanks in advance!

[image]